# CSS framework that support Internet Explorer 6, 8 out of the box

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8

I am developing a new web application that *must* support Internet Explorer 6 and 8 (it's a strict requirements).
I planned to use a CSS framework (like Twitter Bootstrap). However, it did not support IE6 8 out of the box; YAML supports IE6 (natively, as written on their website).
Do you have experience in any other CSS frameworks that supports IE6, 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/) and [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/). Both have support for MSIE 6 out of the box.

[YUI Library Browser Support](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/environments/)

[Blueprint CSS supporting MSIE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864781/making-blueprint-css-working-in-ie-6-and-ie-7)

Comment: Also bootstrap 2.3.2 if you will be happy with IE7+ (IE6 is really uncommon thing) based on 30 000 computers on which my software is installed, there are only 3 computers with IE6 and they are actually using Edge as default browser, so, nobody is using IE6 for real browsing on average base. Just for information IE7 is on 6 computers (but not as default browser), BUT IE8 is on 4366 computers and 546 of them is as default browser. IE9 only on 446 and 38 of them is as default browser.